# Error setonclickListener undefined for the type button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello i'm getting the error:

> the method setonclickListener(new onclickListener(){}) is undefined
>   for the type button

Here's my code:

```
public class Sliding extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private LinearLayout MenuList;
    private Button btnToggleMenuList;
    private int screenWidth;
    private boolean isExpanded;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding);
        MenuList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
        btnToggleMenuList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

        btnToggleMenuList.setonclickListener(new onclickListener() {
            public void onclick(View v) {
                if (isExpanded) {
                    isExpanded = false;
                    MenuList.startAnimation(new CollapseAnimation(MenuList, 0,(int)(screenWidth*0.7), 20));
                }else {
                    isExpanded = true;
                    MenuList.startAnimation(new ExpandAnimation(MenuList, 0,(int)(screenWidth*0.7), 20));
                }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

can anyone tells me why?

Comment: import android.view.View.OnClickListener; and use setOnClickListener instead-of setonclickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
btnToggleMenuList.setonclickListener(new onclickListener() {
        public void onclick(View v) {
```

By

```
btnToggleMenuList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

Also make sure you have the below import statement

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
View.OnClickListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
btnToggleMenuList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
```

Rather than:

```
btnToggleMenuList.setonclickListener(new onclickListener() {
    public void onclick(View v) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  btnToggleMenuList.setonclickListener(new onclickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onclick(View v) {
```